# How do I timeout the wait on a redis pool

Tags: go, redis

I am using https://github.com/gomodule/redigo for my pooled redis connection,

The `redis.Pool` struct looks as follows

```
type Pool struct {
    // Dial is an application supplied function for creating and configuring a
    // connection.
    //
    // The connection returned from Dial must not be in a special state
    // (subscribed to pubsub channel, transaction started, ...).
    Dial func() (Conn, error)

    // DialContext is an application supplied function for creating and configuring a
    // connection with the given context.
    //
    // The connection returned from Dial must not be in a special state
    // (subscribed to pubsub channel, transaction started, ...).
    DialContext func(ctx context.Context) (Conn, error)

    // TestOnBorrow is an optional application supplied function for checking
    // the health of an idle connection before the connection is used again by
    // the application. Argument t is the time that the connection was returned
    // to the pool. If the function returns an error, then the connection is
    // closed.
    TestOnBorrow func(c Conn, t time.Time) error

    // Maximum number of idle connections in the pool.
    MaxIdle int

    // Maximum number of connections allocated by the pool at a given time.
    // When zero, there is no limit on the number of connections in the pool.
    MaxActive int

    // Close connections after remaining idle for this duration. If the value
    // is zero, then idle connections are not closed. Applications should set
    // the timeout to a value less than the server's timeout.
    IdleTimeout time.Duration

    // If Wait is true and the pool is at the MaxActive limit, then Get() waits
    // for a connection to be returned to the pool before returning.
    Wait bool

    // Close connections older than this duration. If the value is zero, then
    // the pool does not close connections based on age.
    MaxConnLifetime time.Duration

    mu           sync.Mutex    // mu protects the following fields
    closed       bool          // set to true when the pool is closed.
    active       int           // the number of open connections in the pool
    initOnce     sync.Once     // the init ch once func
    ch           chan struct{} // limits open connections when p.Wait is true
    idle         idleList      // idle connections
    waitCount    int64         // total number of connections waited for.
    waitDuration time.Duration // total time waited for new connections.
}
```

The `pool.Get` function get a connection from the pool, if the `Wait` flag is turned on, it waits for a connection to be available

Is there a way to set timeout for this waiting period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GetContext](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Pool.GetContext) with a cancelable context.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()
conn, err := pool.GetContext(ctx)
```